# C# Facebook API Get all status or last status message

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get all my status messages using the following code:

```
public dynamic downloadStatuses(FacebookOAuthResult facebookOAuthResult, string userInput)
    {
        dynamic result = null;
        if (facebookOAuthResult != null)
        {
            if (facebookOAuthResult.IsSuccess)
            {
                this.accessToken = facebookOAuthResult.AccessToken;
                var fb = new FacebookClient(facebookOAuthResult.AccessToken);
                result = fb.Get(userInput + "/statuses?format=json&limit=1500");
                return result;

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(facebookOAuthResult.ErrorDescription);
                return result;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

userInput would be my Facebook ID. Some statuses are returned but definitely does not total up to the 1500 that I have indicated. Was wondering if anyone knew how to access your first ever facebook status message or retrieve all the status message by slightly modifying the request url in the code. Is it a must to use fql?

Answer (score 0):

When you query /statuses you don't get the Photo/Album/video related statuses/entries from your stream (including their comments etc). This also includes event creation and questions.

You will have to query the API with separate calls (i.e. /me/photos) to get everything. If you want to have almost the full stream of some person or page or group. Consider using FQL, querying the stream table.

EDIT : Just saw this question is probably outdated, my bad